# Using a ServiceStack Generated SOAP 1.1 Service in Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, soap, flash-builder, servicestack

I have been tinkering around with [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) to expose some web services and have been very impressed.

One potential consumer of these services will be a Flex application.  Flash Builder (the Flex IDE) has a tool that auto-generates proxy AS3 classes for SOAP web services based on the wsdl - at this point in time only for SOAP 1.1.

If I recreate the [HelloWorld](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/) tutorial, and try to use the SOAP 1.1 wsdl to autogenerate classes, I get the following errors in Flash Builder.

```
There was an error during service introspection.
  The part 'parameters' has an invalid value 'HelloResponse' defined for its element. Element declarations must refer to valid values defined in a schema.
  The part 'parameters' has an invalid value 'Hello' defined for its element. Element declarations must refer to valid values defined in a schema.
```

I am sure this is a problem with Flash Builder's tool.  I am wondering if anyone has been successful in auto-generating AS3 classes from a ServiceStack wsdl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many moons ago one of the original consumers of the ServiceStack framework was from Flash using the code-gen built-into Flash Builder, we still have a special option for tweaking the WSDLs to workaround problems with Flash Builders handling of Guids which you can access with:

- **/soap11?flash=true**

Is it still the same problem if you use the **/soap12?flash=true** WSDL?

The approach we took on the project was to use Flash Builders code-gen to generate the types but instead only used them as DTOs which we re-used with a generic XmlServiceClient allowing us to use the faster XML endpoints instead of the SOAP ones. (I'll open source the class somewhere if I can find it).

Although the approach I would take now would be just to use dynamic models and JSON endpoints since the [JSON Serializer is much faster](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) and leaner than even the XML endpoints.

I can't test this as I don't have Flash Builder installed, but if you can save the WSDL locally and massage the output so that Flash Builder likes it, I can look at incorporating the changes under the **flash=true** WSDL flag.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer.  I don't have much for the service right now (hence the usage of HelloWorld), but once I do and finagle with the wsdl, Ill be sure to post it back here.